# $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, locally 1-1 implies $f$ globally 1- 1

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and locally 1-1. I want to show it is globally 1-1 (without assuming the existence of $f'$).

The intermediate value theorem implies that $f$ is locally strictly monotonic.  Intuitively, I would like to show that if $f(a)=f(b)$, then somewhere between $a$ and $b$, $\,f$ must "switch directions", but I haven't had any traction with this strategy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already a theorem that says that a continuous function assumes a maximum on a closed interval $[a,\, b]$?

Comment: If $f(a)=f(b)$, look at the maximum $M$ of $f$ in $[a,b]$. (If it is $a$, then look at the minimum.) Now consider a neighborhood of $M$.

Comment: Thanks, guys, that solves it!

Comment: @GitGud Presumably, it means every point in the domain has some neighborhood on which $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: @DanielFischer It seems we have the same theorem for $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, or indeed if $f$ is defined on any convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, since if $f(p)=f(q)$, then consider the line from $p$ to $q$...$f$ takes a maximum on that line, and $p_{\max}$ cannot have a neighborhood on which it is 1-1. Is this correct?

Comment: @EricAuld For $d > 1$, a continuous function $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is open and non-empty can never be locally $1$-$1$. Consider a small closed path near any point. If you consider functions $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^d$, those can be locally $1$-$1$ without being globally $1$-$1$. (If you already know it, consider the complex exponential function, otherwise $(x,\,y) \mapsto (e^x\cos y,\, e^x\sin y)$.)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prove the similar statement that a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is injective if and only if it has no local extrema. (If you're stuck, [it's discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248674/prove-that-a-continuous-function-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-is-injective-if-and).)

Assuming that statement is true, then the result is easy. Indeed, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous but not injective, then $f$ has a local extrema at some $x_0$, and it follows (show this) that $f$ is not locally injective at $x_0$.

**Edit:** I didn't notice the comments before posting this. The solution there is similar but more to the point.