# Under which additional hypothesis are open maps locally injective

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds

**Recollection of basic definitions:** We recall the basic definitions that a continous map of topological spaces 
$f : X \to Y$ is open if $f(U)$ is an open subset of $Y$ whenever $U$ is an open subset of $X$. A continous map is locally injective if for every $x \in X$ there is an open subset of $x$ in $X$ such that the restriction to $U$ denoted $f|_U$ is injective.

**My question:**
Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is an open map of topological spaces. Then under which hypothesis (if any) on $X$ and $Y$ is $f$ locally injective?

In the simple case when $X$ and $Y$ are both $\mathbb{R}$, I don't even see how to produce an open map which is not a homeomorphism, which suggests that perhaps it is atleast true for say topological manifolds.

Comment: The constant map to a one-point space is open, but locally injective only at isolated points ...

Comment: The question is under which hypothesis it becomes true, not under which is not true. Otherwise thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The maps $p:X\to Y$ both open and locally injective you are looking for are, practically  tautologically, the local homeomorphisms.
An alternative terminology (especially  for us ze  French)  is that $X$ is an étalé space  over $Y$.
They are very important and correspond to the historical definition of sheaves, before the definition of sheaves as functors took over (but see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6477/450)).

b) The most common way  of obtaining a local homeomorphism is to take a smooth  map  $f:X\to Y$ between differential manifolds and to check that its differntial $T_xf:T_xX\to T_xY$ is a vector space isomorphism for all $x\in X$ : this guarantees that $f$ will  even be a local diffeomorphism.

c) A purely topological source for étalé spaces consists of covering spaces.
Indeed, every covering space is an étalé space, but of course not conversely:
The inclusion $j:U\hookrightarrow X$ of any open subset $U$  of a topological space $X$ into that space is a local homeomorphism,  but practically never a covering space.

d) Finally , every local homeomorphism $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is indeed injective and thus gives rise to a homeomorphism $f: \mathbb R\to f(\mathbb R)$.
This is illustrated by $f(x)=e^x$ and is a rather elementary result in calculus: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444552/f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-continuous-locally-1-1-implies-f-globally-1-1).

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer!

Comment: Do you happen to know of any cases where open map implies local homeomorphism?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words Oliver. To answer your second comment: no, I don't know a reasonable condition. As a *caveat*, beware that the projection $X\times Y\to X$ of a product of topological spaces onto a factor is **always** open and **practically never** a local homeomorphism. Similarly a submersion $X\to Y$ of differential manifolds is **always** open but **never** a  local homeomorphism if $\dim X\gt \dim Y$  ,